# React, React Router and Flux: “dispatch in the middle of a dispatch” when I try to clear the messages on store

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

I'm using React, React Router and Flux.

I have a `MessageStore` that holds the messages (error, warning or success) that the components of my application trigger using `MessagesAction.addError()`, `MessagesAction.addWarning()` and `MessagesAction.addSucess()`.

The message is dispatched and the `MessageStore` is registered on the Dispatcher to receive the message and store the message.

After that, the store emit an event to call the callback methods listening for new messages. Nothing new until here.

My problem is: I need to clear the messages on the `MessageStore` when the path (URL) is changed.

My first try is listen the route changes and dispatch an action to clear the messages. The code:

**generic-component.jsx**

```
onClickButton: updateGenericInformation() {
    GenericAction.updateInformation(this.state.information);
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    //listening for the update in GenericStore.
    GenericStore.addChangeListener(this.changeRoute);
}

changeRoute: function () {
    this.history.pushState(null, '/my-page');
},
```

**routes.jsx**

```
clearMessages: function() {
    MessagesAction.clear();
},

ReactDOM.render(<Router onUpdate={this.clearMessages}>{routes}</Router>, appElement);
```

**MessagesAction**

```
clear: function() {
    Dispatcher.dispatch({ // error happen here...
        actionType: 'CLEAR'
    });
}
```

**MessagesStore**

```
case 'CLEAR':
    _messages = [];
    EventEmitter.prototype.emit('EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED');
    break;
```

The error:

```
flux.js:41 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

Actually, to clear the messages, each component calls the clear action from `MessagesAction` in his own DidMount method, what is not a good solution.

I tried too to clear the messages in my messages component in the update cycle of the component (after I receive the message and save in the state):

**messages.jsx**

```
componentDidUpdate function() {
    if (this.state.messages) {
         MessagesAction.clear();
    }
}
```

I receive the same error.

So, what is the good practice in React and Flux to do this? I would like to not use `setTimeout` in the solution.

Comment: Why do you need to listen to route changes using some store? `onUpdate` handler is fired by React Router whenever it detects route change.

Comment: And what kind of error happens when you try to do dispatch `CLEAR` action?

Comment: @KonstantinGrushetsky, hi! Thanks for your attention. When the route changes, I need to clear the MessagesStore. I'm not using a specific store (like a "PathStore") to save the path and listen the change from this store. I added the error too.

Comment: Yes, the issue is that you can't dispatch an event from the store (like this)  - the dispatcher waits for all the callbacks to complete and you're dispatching this new event synchronously. It's an issue with your design; however, one way around it is to make an ajax call (for example) which will be asynchronous (you can emit on the callback of that), or do what you don't want to do (hacky) - with a timeout, which again is asynchronous eg. something like 

`var self = this;

setTimeout(function() {
  self.emit('EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED');
}, 0);`

Comment: @David_001, I'm trying to resolve this issue in my design, but I don't know the available options for that. I would like to not use `setTimeout` solutions.

Comment: @Dherik, this is the exact use case for `setImmediate` (or it's longer version `setTimeout(fn, 0)`). Why not use it and complicate an otherwise working flow?

Comment: @elektronik Hi! `setTimeout` "is a hack and should be avoided" (https://github.com/facebook/flux/issues/138#issuecomment-88969327).

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with something like this, I just put this in my routes file.

```
browserHistory.listen(location => {
    // fire your action here to clear the state you need
});
```

I'm not sure the same mechanism is in place, but when I've tried to add change handlers on the route itself, proper, I'd have more issues than I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Fix rule here. You can't emit another event inside the store, store should be purely synchronous. so this line is the issue.
"EventEmitter.prototype.emit('EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED');"

**So I'm guessing you're trying to achieve something like this**

1. componentDidMount/Update()
2. Shout "Clear! (CLEAR)" to Mr. A (Message Store)
3. Message has been cleared
4. Let Mr.A shout again to Mr. B (Some other store) "It has been cleared! (EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED)"

(Note: Shout is equal to dispatching thing)

**You could reduce flow to.**

1. componentDidMount/Update()
2. Shout "Clear! (CLEAR)"
3. Have Mr.A (MessageStore) and Mr.B (SomeOtherStore) both listen to 'CLEAR' and do stuff respectively.

so your MessageStore will be

```
case 'CLEAR':
    _messages = [];
    break;
```

And your Mr. B (some other store that originally listened to 'EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED', let it listen to 'CLEAR' instead

```
// case 'EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED'
case 'CLEAR':
    // Do something you intend to do after EVENT_MESSAGES_UPDATED
    break;
```

Comment: Hi! My problem is that I'm still dispatching with `GenericAction` when the URL changes an do another dispatch using `MessagesAction` from my routes.jsx. The `Generic` store (and other stores) doesn't need to know about the action of clear messages.